# AS3 Mouseover Action to change movie clip in background

Tags: actionscript-3, mouseover, movie

I try to put some MouseOver actions on different spots over a running movie clip. Each spot will change the movie clip while hovering over the specific spot. The MouseOver buttons (invisible) should stay while the clip in the background changes.

I tried firstly to ump from scene to scene when you hover over the button, but this may not be the best solve.

My problem is that I'm in the very beginning of AS3 programming, so my code example might not be very helpful...

```
    btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OVER, btnOver);
    btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.ROLL_OUT, btnOut);

    function btnOver(event:MouseEvent):void{  
    btn.gotoAndPlay("scene 2");
    }
    function btnOut(event:MouseEvent):void{
    btn.gotoAndPlay("main");
    }
```

Are there some possibilities or even good ways to solve it?

PS: maybe there are better ways to solve it (f.E.Javascript?) Just tell me!

Comment: Do you have a code sample? There are a multitude of different ways this can be done (in flash) and without a code sample it is hard to help you.

Comment: not sure if this is an error in your posting of the code or an error with the code but your second function, `fuction btnOut(event:MouseEvent):void { ... }` should be -> `function btnOut(event:MouseEvent):void { ... }`.

Comment: I suggest you add one listener to the whole `MovieClip` and in mouse over function change what you want using the `currentFrame` or `currentLabel` property of the `MovieClip`.